# How to pass value from attribute lightning component to apex controller without apex

Tags: lightning-aura-components, javascript, custom-field, user, get

I have a component with an attribute. I try to pass the value to the controller without succes. How do I achieve this.

**Aura component**

```
    <aura:attribute name="currentUser" type="User"/>

<force:recordData aura:id="recordLoader" recordId="{!$SObjectType.CurrentUser.Id}"  fields="Return_URL__c" targetFields="{!v.currentUser}"/>
     {!v.currentUser.Return_URL__c}
```

**Controller**

```
let userCustomField = component.get("v.userRecord").Return_URL__c;
```

The field is rendering correctly in the component. What am I mising.
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The attribute was called `currentUser`, but you wrote `v.userRecord` in your controller/helper. Also, `force:recordData` loads data asynchronously, so you can't access that data in `init`. Instead, wait for the record to be loaded:

```
<force:recordData recordUpdated="{!c.init}" ...
```